# getting results of distinct columns in to a single column

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, distinct

I have a table which has:

```
col1     col2     ...     Plastname     Pfirstname     Clastname      Cfirstname
1        abc              Smith         John           Robinson       Bob
2        xyz              Smith         John           Jones          Michael
3        bda              Robinson      Bob            Smith          John
```

What I want is a single list of distinct names, like:

```
col1
Smith, John
Robinson, Bob
Jones, Michael
```

I've tried a union doing:

```
select distinct Plastname + ', ' + Pfirstname as name from table
union
select distinct Clastname + ', ' + Cfirstname as name from table
```

But that doesn't give me the clastname and cfirstname 's.

I've also tried some various attempts at using distinct and group by but haven't gotten anything to work.

Any advice or direction is much appreciated!

Comment: What platform? PostgreSQL, SQL Server, MySQL, Oracle?

Comment: sql-server, thanks.  Updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe with a subquery which concats all four columns as pairs and a `GROUP BY` on the result:

```
SELECT X.NAME FROM
(
    SELECT Plastname + ', ' + Pfirstname AS NAME
    FROM People
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Clastname + ', ' + Cfirstname AS NAME
    FROM People
) X
GROUP BY X.NAME
ORDER BY X.NAME
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bc233/2/0)</kbd>

or even **easier**: replace the `UNION ALL` with `UNION` which eliminates duplicates:

```
SELECT Plastname + ', ' + Pfirstname AS NAME
FROM People
UNION 
SELECT Clastname + ', ' + Cfirstname AS NAME
FROM People
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bc233/5/0)</kbd>

Comment: It should use a `UNION` rather than a `UNION ALL`. "Robinson, Bob" will be a dupe if you use `ALL`.

Comment: @Declan_K: I have already added that, i was thinking too complicated first :)

Comment: @decken_k: have you seen the group by in the first approach?

Comment: Yes, but that is redundant if you just use `UNION`.

Comment: I want to +1 this just for the fancy DEMO buttons! :)

Comment: Ah, was just missing the surrounding select x.name from () group by x.name.  Works like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I checked your query and it work fine http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bac7f/4
but suggest to use the separation of each row with four columns into two rows with two columns.

Example on SQLServer2008+

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.lastname + ', ' + o.firstname AS name
FROM dbo.test142 t 
  CROSS APPLY(
              VALUES(Plastname, Pfirstname),
                    (Clastname, Cfirstname)
              ) o(lastname, firstname)
```

See demo on [`SQLFiddle`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bac7f/1)